# how to create php project in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, phpunit

I want to know to create php project in jenkins, Actually I have created a test case to using phpunit 
I am getting this issue:

Started by anonymous user
    Checkstyle: 0 warnings.

```
No warnings since build 3.
New zero warnings highscore: no warnings since yesterday!
During parsing an error has been reported.

PMD: 0 warnings.

No warnings since build 3.
New zero warnings highscore: no warnings since yesterday!
During parsing an error has been reported.

Duplicate Code: 0 warnings.

No warnings since build 3.
New zero warnings highscore: no warnings since yesterday!
During parsing an error has been reported.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian Bergmann has created a template for configuring his tools, and the PHP pipeline in Jenkins.  See the Guide [Here](http://jenkins-php.org/)